# How to extract only the string component between parenthesis?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, etl, data-cleaning

I am looking for an efficient way to remove specific elements from a column of data.

I have data like this:

```
year
1 (1991)
10 (1991-2001)
8 (1991-1998)
2 (2000-2002)
```

and I wanted to be like this:

```
year
1991
1991 - 2001
1991 - 1998
2000 - 2002
```

I want to remove the parentheses and elements before and after parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

### With a regular expression:

- Use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

  - Regular expression: `\((.*)\)`
  - Extracts content between `()`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1 (1991)', '10 (1991-2001)', '8 (1991-1998)', '2 (2000-2002)']})

           year
       1 (1991)
 10 (1991-2001)
  8 (1991-1998)
  2 (2000-2002)

df['year'] = df['year'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')

      year
      1991
 1991-2001
 1991-1998
 2000-2002
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str.split('(').str[1].str.strip(')')
```

**output**

```
    year
0   1991
1   1991-2001
2   1991-1998
3   2000-2002
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str[1:-1]
```

Or safer if your data don't always start/end with `'()'`:

```
# str.strip accepts regex
df['year'] = df['year'].str.strip('(|)')
```

Output:

```
1          1991
10    1991-2001
8     1991-1998
2     2000-2002
Name: year, dtype: object
```